# Cannot connect to my webserver from LAN or WAN on Windows 7

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, lan, webserver

I am running windows 7. I have disabled the windows firewall. I have selected home network, even so, I cannot connect to my apache or any server which I run on windows 7 from any device on the network(LAN). On the same machine when I run my server on a linux VM I am able to connect from WAN to my public IP but am still not able to connect to winows 7 from the VM(LAN). On the windows I cannot access from either WAN or LAN except from the machine itself, both "localhost" and '192.168.x.x' are reachable. I primarily use linux so I am not familiar with windows networking options that much. Something seems to be blocking access. Could HOMEGROUP have something to do with this? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What's Homegroup? Can you ping the Win machine from LAN?

Comment: @Albin No, I can't. I mentioned HOMEGROUP because that's the only recent change I have made to my system. Created one. That's it. I don't know if it affects network discovery(It shouldn't). Only firewall blocks access from LAN..so I disabled it. Nothing else should block access. Still the WIN 7 machine is not visible to other devices on LAN. The port forwarding is fine because it works fine on the Linux VM. I can get my site on NO-IP. I don't know what to check on windows.

Comment: If you can't ping the Win7 client from the LAN (only via local host), s.th. is "blocking" incoming traffic. How about outgoing traffic can you ping devices **from** the Win7 client?

Answer (score 0):

Can you run telnet to the port number to make sure it is actually open?

```
telnet 192.168.x.x 80
telnet 192.168.x.x 443
```

Also, you said you were familiar with Linux install nmap and scan the machine to see open ports.

Comment: The port is open, otherwise I wouldn't be able to connect to my server from WAN on VM as well.

Comment: So you can get to the web server from the WAN? Just not locally?

Comment: @user240163 It's a verification question because sometimes people write the wrong thing by mistake or in your case it's just flat out not clear, buddy.

Comment: @HazardousGlitch what information seems missing?

Comment: So you have a public IP bound to this web server? So the internal addresses don't know how to route to the public address?  Are they on the same subnet, please provide more of the network information.

Comment: Yes they are on the same subnet. The relevance is only that the port forwarding is fine. Linux VM can connect to the NO-IP address. However on windows, apache or Tinyserver or Flask none of the servers are accessible from outside on any port. Also the local address is also not accessible to other devices on the same network. That's what I said..I don't know what @HazardousGlitch is on about.